# Problems with GWTP mergelocales.py

Tags: python, gwt, gwtp

I'm trying to use the mergelocales.py script but I can't get it working.

In my ui.xml (the one that I am using to test it) I have this locales:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    ui:generateFormat='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat'
    ui:generateKeys="com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator"
    ui:generateLocales="en_US, es_ES"
    ui:defaultLocale="es_ES"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
```

Then I compile my project using "-extra extras" argument. This generates an "extras" directory in my project wich haves a folder called "myModule" and inside this folder are the generated .properties files:

```
/myproject/extras/myModule/com.mycompany.myproject.client.mvp.views.MyViewImplMyViewImplUiBinderImplGenMessages_en_US.properties
/myproject/extras/myModule/com.mycompany.myproject.client.mvp.views.MyViewImplMyViewImplUiBinderImplGenMessages_es_ES.properties
```

Now, I am trying to run the mergelocales.py to get the LocalizableResources*.properties files and when I try to run:

python2.5 ~/Downloads/mergelocales.py extras/myModule src/main/java/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/

I get the following stack trace:

```
Skipping non-default locale in extra directory: com.mycompany.myproject.client.mvp.views.MyViewImplMyViewImplUiBinderImplGenMessages_en_US.properties
Skipping non-default locale in extra directory: com.mycompany.myproject.client.mvp.views.MyViewImplMyViewImplUiBinderImplGenMessages_es_ES.properties
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Downloads/mergelocales.py", line 497, in <module>
    main()    
  File "/Users/admin/Downloads/mergelocales.py", line 131, in main
    mergeLocales( args[0], args[1] )
  File "/Users/admin/Downloads/mergelocales.py", line 466, in mergeLocales
    pathname = os.path.join( resourcesDir, defaultLocaleFilename )
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py", line 60, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Is there something that I am missing to get this script working?

Comment: Are you certain you have a new enough version of python? 2.5 seems fairly old to me, superseded by 2.7 in 2010, and 3.0 somewhat more recently.

Comment: Also tried using python 2.7 and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

**Now, I am trying to run the mergelocales.py to get the LocalizableResources*.properties files and [...] I get the following stack trace...**

You have to create the blank LocalizableResource.properties files **manually** yourself and they will be populated by mergeLocales script. See here:

*Let’s say we would like our application to also be available in French. **We need to create two empty files** named LocalizableResource.properties and LocalizableResource_fr.properties. The LocalizableResource.properties will contain the default (English) texts, whereas the LocalizableResource_fr.properties, will contain the French texts. Those files should be located in src/main/resources/com/google/gwt/i18n/client.*

from http://blog.arcbees.com/2015/09/15/i18n-using-gwts-uibinder/